# Convert function to Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am new to Rx world and I am finding it hard to convert the piece of code below to RX.

```
foreach (var filterGridStatusItem in FilterStatusItems)
{
    if (filterGridStatusItem.FilerValue.Equals(selectedItem.FilerValue))
    {
        if (!selectedItem.IsSelected)
        {
            filterGridStatusItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            filterGridStatusItem.IsSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want this, what improvement do think it will give? At a glance it does not seem to be code that will benefit from using Rx

Comment: Hello @PeterBons I want to re-write it in RX as I believe it cleaner and more expressive. Kind regards.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand what RX is or when it makes sense to use. I suggest you go through http://introtorx.com to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, Rx is not a good fit for this scenario. In your case there is a limited, fixed set of items that can be better managed using Linq, for example like this:

```
foreach (var filterGridStatusItem in FilterStatusItems
                       .Where(fsi => fsi.FilerValue.Equals(selectedItem.FilerValue))
{
    filterGridStatusItem.IsSelected = !selectedItem.IsSelected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Rx version of your code:

```
var query =
    from filterGridStatusItem in FilterStatusItems.ToObservable()
    where filterGridStatusItem.FilerValue.Equals(selectedItem.FilerValue)
    select new { filterGridStatusItem, selectedItem.IsSelected };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(x => x.filterGridStatusItem.IsSelected = !x.IsSelected);
```

Now, just for comparison, here's the optimised version of your code:

```
foreach (var filterGridStatusItem in FilterStatusItems)
{
    if (filterGridStatusItem.FilerValue.Equals(selectedItem.FilerValue))
    {
        filterGridStatusItem.IsSelected = !selectedItem.IsSelected;
    }
}
```

And now a LINQ version:

```
var query =
    from filterGridStatusItem in FilterStatusItems
    where filterGridStatusItem.FilerValue.Equals(selectedItem.FilerValue)
    select new { filterGridStatusItem, selectedItem.IsSelected };

foreach (var x in query)
{
    x.filterGridStatusItem.IsSelected = !x.IsSelected;
}
```

In this case I kind of feel that the optimised version of your code is best - both in terms of clarity and performance.